# checkbox in vuejs and laravel

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I want to generate checkbox using v-for and use v-model. But i am having difficult time trying the get the value of checkbox. Here is what i am doing. My view looks like this:

```
<div class="checkbox" v-for="role in userRole">
     <label>
       <input v-model="newUser.urole" type="checkbox"
               value="@{{role.roName}}">@{{role.roName}}</label>
</div>
```

Here is my Vue Js:

```
var emailRe = /^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#userMgt',
    data: {
        newUser:{
            fname: '',
            mname: '',
            lname: '',
            email: '',
            username: '',
            password: '',
            conpassword: '',
            utype: '',
            urole:''
        },


    },
    methods: {
        fetchUser: function () {
            this.$http.get('../api/users', function (data) {
                this.$set('users', data)
            });
        },
        fetchUserType: function () {
            this.$http.get('../api/usertype', function (data) {
                this.$set('userType', data);
            });
        },
        fetchUserRole: function () {
            this.$http.get('../api/role', function (data) {
                this.$set('userRole', data);
            });
        },
        AddNewUser: function(){
            //user input
            var user = this.newUser;
            alert(user.urole)  ///not alerting right info
            //clear form input
            this.newUser = {fname:'',mname:'',lname:'',email:'',username:'',password:'',conpassword:'',utype:'',urole:''};

            this.$http.post('../api/users', user);
            ;
        },
        selectAll: function(){

        }

    },
    computed: {


    },

    ready: function () {
        this.fetchUser();
        this.fetchUserType();
        this.fetchUserRole();
    }

});
```

I am not able to get the selected value in `newUser.urole` and more over all my checkbox gets selected when i click one. How can i do this?. Thanks

Comment: `urole` should be an empty array instead of an empty string

Comment: ahh..that worked thanks.. but the second time i click on the checkbox, everything gets selected?...anything i am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are binding all your check boxes to the same data object